# Dynamically generate hyperlink with keypress (without submit) in Flask App

Tags: javascript, python, jquery, flask, jinja2

https://jsfiddle.net/mjcyezh0/

I'm creating a Flask webapp for work and on the main page, I ask my users if they're an interviewer at the company. If they select YES, I prompt them for their ID (i.e. 290).

In another space on the page, I've used jinja2 to programmatically loop through a dictionary of questions and links to generate a series of questions, hyperlinks and inputs for my user; this will allow them to answer questions and have helpful links that are customized for the current time/date.

One of the hyperlinks sends the user to a custom search in our interviewer platform, but the only way to direct them to the right place is to have that ID within the URL, (i.e: `website.com/###/interviewers/.....`)

**Questions re: Javascript**

1. Is there anyway that using .keypress and (no onclick/button submission), I can dynamically populate the content WITHIN the href of that particular link? (post-completion is fine)
2. If yes, how can I fit this into my jinja2 {% for %} loop to address the ONE specific entry? *(row 12, when `x['tech_key'] == 'int')* [That is, do I want to add a particular ID/CLASS to it in order to run the js code?]

Code attached for my for-loop:

```
1  <div class="col-md-8">
2
3   {% for k,v in inps['sheet'].items() %}
4     {% for x in v %}
5       {% if x['question'] is not number %}
6 
7       <div class="{{x['tech_key']}}">
8         <hr class="thicker">
9         <b>{{x['question']}}</b>
10        <button class="add_form_field" data-key="{{x['tech_key']}}"><b>+</b></button><br>
11        {% for i in ['1', '2', '3'] if x['link'+i] is not number%}
12**          <a href="{{x['link'+i]}}" target="_blank">{{x['text'+i]}}</a>{{ " | " if not loop.last }}
13        {% endfor %}<br>
14
15        {% if x['subtext'] is not number%}
16          <i><p style="font-size: 12px;overflow:auto">{{x['subtext']}}</p></i>
17        {% endif %}
18        <div><input type="text" name="{{x['tech_key']}}1" size="80px"></div>
19      </div>
20      {% endif %}
21    {% endfor %}
22  {% endfor %}
23 </div>
```

Comment: If the content shown is rendered before the user gets asked for id then the only way to modify the href is with javascript. There is no flask or jinja in browser, only on server. Modifying the href of an `<a>` is failry simple and you could build the url string once the user input is complete

Comment: Would need more detail about the id entry and if it goes in the input shown or  elsewhere

Comment: @charlietfl Correct, that's why I asked for a jquery/javascript answer. :) I'm unsure if I need to apply a particular class or id to that entry and what the javascript code itself would be.

Comment: Yes regarding identifiers...break this down to just a rendered html sample with no server code showing which is the id input with a  class (or id if only one) and class on the link(s) as well s better outline of the url structure needed. Then can make a runnable demo for it. Several easy ways to get copy of the rendered html if need help there also

Comment: Edited to include JSFiddle link. https://jsfiddle.net/mjcyezh0/

Comment: This is rough but is very late for me , give you an idea anyway https://jsfiddle.net/phmsqc0b/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need the build the link URL after retrieving the interviewer id:

First give your elements an id:

```
<input type="text" id="form_interviewer_id" name="interviewer_id" value="" >
<a id="linkAnchor" href="https://example.com/interviewer/0?start_date=2020-07-01">palp</a>
```

Then you can access them via JavaScript:

```
window.onload = function() {
    var textField = document.getElementById("form_interviewer_id");
    textField.onkeyup = function(evt) {
        evt = evt || window.event;
        if (evt.keyCode == 13 || this.value.length == 2) { // Updated
            var linkAnchor = document.getElementById("linkAnchor");
            linkAnchor.href = getLink(textField.value);
        }
    };
};

function getLink(id) {
    return "https://example.com/" + id + "/0?start_date=2020-07-01";
}
```

Updated Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/63onu9dm/ [**Updated**]

Comment: But they still have to click "enter" on the field, correct? There's no way that just typing it in can fill out the link? (THIS IS SUPER CLOSE THOUGH.)

Comment: They need to press the enter-key. This solution looks for `onkeyup` events. Instead of checking for "enter" (`evt.keyCode == 13`), you could just check `textField.value.length == 2` depending on the length of your interviewer ids. I updated my answer.